# Laravel registration: Insert two rows into separated tables

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with inserting rows in Laravel.

**Theory:** I use simple Laravel authentication and have two tables.

- users: id, name, password.
- user_details: id, userID, email

After the registration it would be useful to insert rows into both tables, and the userID = id (in users table).

**RegisterController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'e_r' => $data['e_r'],

        ]);

        $details = UserDetails::create([
            'firstname' => 'joco',
            'lastname' => 'nagy',
            'email' =>$data['email'],
            'position' => 'cleaner',
            'salary' => '250000',
            'amount_holiday' => '40'
        ]);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

(I have just tried to insert fake datas. There are default values in migration files.)

Models:

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'e_r',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function user_detail(){
       return $this->hasOne("App\UserDetails");
    }

}
```

**Error:**

> FatalThrowableError in RegisterController.php line 74: Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\UserDetails' not found

I do not understand why should be my model in Auth directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you include your model `UserDetails`?

Include it on top:

```
use App\User;
use App\UserDetails;
```

or

Change `UserDetails` to `App\UserDetails`.

```
$details = App\UserDetails::create([
        'firstname' => 'joco',
        'lastname' => 'nagy',
        'email' =>$data['email'],
        'position' => 'cleaner',
        'salary' => '250000',
        'amount_holiday' => '40'
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks! It solved, but unfortunatelly an other error occured:
ReflectionException in RouteSignatureParameters.php line 39:
Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::register() does not exist

Answer (score 1):

You should use `use` statement eg. `use Your\Name\Space\UserDetails;`

Without this declaration PHP is looking for UserDetails class in your current namespace, in your case `App\Http\Controllers\Auth`. That's why you get

> 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\UserDetails' not found

Comment: Thanks! It solved, but unfortunatelly an other error occured:
ReflectionException in RouteSignatureParameters.php line 39:
Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::register() does not exist